# SQL pull data to another column SUBSTRING CHARINDEX

Tags: sql, sql-server

Below Data example in one field of the database

```
Sizing Specification: Type A Specification, Equipment: For Vehicles with 
type x, Connectors type: Push in, Weight [kg]: 0.65, Voltage [V]: 6, Number
of Poles: 2, Number of Inlets / Outlets: 1
```

I would like to try and extract the weight into a seperate column if the weight exists. So far I have the following code within my select statement.

```
SUBSTRING(dbo.fullresult.PRODINFO, CHARINDEX('Weight ', dbo.fullresult.PRODINFO), 17)
```

This gets me `Weight [kg]: 0.65` into a seperate column but I would like to display just `0.65`. Ideally I need the text after Weight [kg] and before the comma to avoid extra characters only where the weight exists.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is one approach, just replace `@string` with your column name:

```
DECLARE @STRING VARCHAR(200) = 'Sizing Specification: Type A Specification, Equipment: For Vehicles with type x, Connectors type: Push in, Weight [kg]: 0.65, Voltage [V]: 6, Number of Poles: 2, Number of Inlets / Outlets: 1'

SELECT SUBSTRING(SUBSTRING(@STRING, CHARINDEX('Weight ', @STRING), 25), CHARINDEX(':',SUBSTRING(@STRING, CHARINDEX('Weight ', @STRING), 25))+2, CHARINDEX(',',SUBSTRING(@STRING + ',', CHARINDEX('Weight ', @STRING), 25))-2 -CHARINDEX(':',SUBSTRING(@STRING, CHARINDEX('Weight ', @STRING), 25)))
```

Probably easier to read if broken down.  It is pulling out the chunk between the `:` and `,` after `Weight`:

```
DECLARE @STRING VARCHAR(200) = 'Sizing Specification: Type A Specification, Equipment: For Vehicles with type x, Connectors type: Push in, Weight [kg]: 0.65, Voltage [V]: 6, Number of Poles: 2, Number of Inlets / Outlets: 1'

SELECT SUBSTRING(@STRING, CHARINDEX('Weight ', @STRING), 25)

DECLARE @STRING2 VARCHAR(200) = SUBSTRING(@STRING, CHARINDEX('Weight ', @STRING), 25)

SELECT SUBSTRING(@STRING2, CHARINDEX(':',@STRING2)+2, CHARINDEX(',',@STRING2)-2 -CHARINDEX(':',@STRING2))
```

Comment: SUBSTRING(SUBSTRING(dbo.fullresult.PRODINFO, CHARINDEX('Weight ', 
                         dbo.fullresult.PRODINFO), 25), CHARINDEX(':', SUBSTRING(dbo.fullresult.PRODINFO, CHARINDEX('Weight ', dbo.fullresult.PRODINFO), 25)) + 2, CHARINDEX(',', SUBSTRING(dbo.fullresult.PRODINFO, 
                         CHARINDEX('Weight ', dbo.fullresult.PRODINFO), 25)) - 2 - CHARINDEX(':', SUBSTRING(dbo.fullresult.PRODINFO, CHARINDEX('Weight ', dbo.fullresult.PRODINFO), 25))) AS Expr1 works until 26 rows in where I get the error "Invalid length parameter passed to the LEFT or SUBSTRING function"

Comment: Possibly where the field doesn't contain a weight

Comment: @Emma Good call, that would do it.  Easiest fix is probably `CASE WHEN dbo.fullresult.PRODINFO LIKE '%Weight%' THEN SUBSTRING(etc) ELSE 0 END`

Comment: Still the same... Invalid length parameter

Comment: CASE WHEN PRODINFO LIKE '%Weight %' THEN SUBSTRING(SUBSTRING(dbo.fullresult.PRODINFO, CHARINDEX('Weight ', dbo.fullresult.PRODINFO), 25), CHARINDEX(':', SUBSTRING(dbo.fullresult.PRODINFO, 
                         CHARINDEX('Weight ', dbo.fullresult.PRODINFO), 25)) + 2, CHARINDEX(',', SUBSTRING(dbo.fullresult.PRODINFO, CHARINDEX('Weight ', dbo.fullresult.PRODINFO), 25)) - 2 - CHARINDEX(':', 
                         SUBSTRING(dbo.fullresult.PRODINFO, CHARINDEX('Weight ', dbo.fullresult.PRODINFO), 25))) ELSE '0' END AS Expr1

Comment: What would happen if weight is in there twice ?

Comment: I can see why, its where weight it at the end of the string with no comma e.g. Vehicle Equipment: type1 Number of Inlets / Outlets: 6, Number of Poles: 4, Voltage [V]: 14, Weight [kg]: 2.18

Comment: So looks like weight can appear mid string or at the end of the string without the comma !

Comment: @Emma Just add a comma to the end of the column in  the comma part: `...(',',SUBSTRING(dbo.fullresult.PRODINFO + ',')...` that way there will always be a final comma for the function to reference :)

Comment: Thanks !! Result !

Answer (score 1):

Another option for you

```
DECLARE @TestData TABLE
    (
        [StringData] NVARCHAR(MAX)
    );

INSERT INTO @TestData (
                          [StringData]
                      )
VALUES ( 'Sizing Specification: Type A Specification, Equipment: For Vehicles with type x, Connectors type: Push in, Voltage [V]: 6, Number of Poles: 2, Number of Inlets / Outlets: 1, Weight [kg]: 50000.00' )
,( 'Sizing Specification: Type A Specification, Equipment: For Vehicles with type x, Connectors type: Push in, Voltage [V]: 6,Weight [kg]: 0.65, Number of Poles: 2, Number of Inlets / Outlets: 1' );



SELECT SUBSTRING(
                    [StringData]
                  , CHARINDEX(
                                ':'
                              , [StringData]
                              , CHARINDEX('Weight', [StringData])
                            ) + 1
                  , CASE WHEN CHARINDEX(
                                           ','
                                         , [StringData]
                                         , CHARINDEX('Weight', [StringData])
                                       ) = 0 THEN LEN([StringData]) + 1  --Case statement check to see if comma is after weight, if it isn't then Weight is at the end.
                         ELSE
                             CHARINDEX(
                                          ','
                                        , [StringData]
                                        , CHARINDEX('Weight', [StringData])
                                      )
                    END
                    - CHARINDEX(
                                   ':'
                                 , [StringData]
                                 , CHARINDEX('Weight', [StringData])
                               ) - 1
                )
FROM   @TestData
WHERE  CHARINDEX('Weight', [StringData]) <> 0;
```

Comment: The number of characters between : and the comma after the weight can vary, some weights are 1 character, some 2, some 3, some 4, some 5 etc.

Comment: @Emma this accounts for that.  It's not static, it will derive that base on the data.  That why in the substring is subtracts where the location of colon is from where the location of the comma is after 'Weight' to determine the number of characters inbetween.

Comment: @Emma you can easily test that. Change "Wright [kg]: 0.65" to "Weight [kg]: 50000.00" and it pulls 50000.00 out.

Comment: Thanks, issue now seems to be some of the weights are actually at the end of the string without a comma !

Comment: @Emma Tricky, moving data :)  I updated the answer to account for that.

Answer (score 0):

You can try following code:

```
SELECT LEFT(SUBSTRING(dbo.fullresult.PRODINFO, PATINDEX('%[0-9.]%'
,dbo.fullresult.PRODINFO),8000),
PATINDEX('%[^0-9.]%',SUBSTRING(dbo.fullresult.PRODINFO,
PATINDEX('%[0-9.]%',dbo.fullresult.PRODINFO),8000) + 'X')- 1)
```

Comment: This works as long as there will never be a number before the weight

Comment: @AaronDietz Yes Aaron, thanks for bringing it to attention. This code will extract first numeric value from the string irrespective of pattern.

Answer (score 0):

Putting your string into a variable...

```
DECLARE @document varchar(500);  
SELECT @document = 'Sizing Specification: Type A Specification, Equipment: For Vehicles with type x, Connectors type: Push in, Weight [kg]: 0.65, Voltage [V]: 6, Number of Poles: 2, Number of Inlets / Outlets: 1';  
SELECT SUBSTRING(@document,(CHARINDEX('[kg]', @document)+6),4)  as WeightKG
```

Substring from the point of the KG (& 6 spaces to the actual weight)